# Sax parser with string input

Tags: android, string, parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse an xml file with SaxParser. I've done this with an url and with an xml file. But now i want to parse it from an string.

This is the string:

```
String xml_string = "<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <NewDataSet> <Table> <expnr>672 </expnr> <artnr>ML-824          </artnr> </Table> <Table> <expnr>672 </expnr> <artnr>ML-824          </artnr> </Table> </NewDataSet> "
```

And now i need to parse that string, i tried this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml_string.getBytes());
                    items = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);
```

but its not working (got error in the arrayadapter)

this is the error:

```
3654-3654/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
    ... 36 more
```

What is the right way to parse this?

EDIT: I found what i did wrong

i was using this code:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(resultFull.getBytes());
                items = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);
                ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter(activty, R.layout.list, items);

                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but i did not use my CustomListViewAdapter like this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(resultFull.getBytes());
                items = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);
                CustomListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(activty, items);

                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lv.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

And with the last code it is working. It was very stupid but i found the solution! Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try? xml_string.getBytes()

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Comment: can you share the error you get?

Comment: i edited the question with the error

Comment: The given error isn't caused by any issues with parsing the XML, it's Android trying to set up your layout.  Can you post code from your activity?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to cast a realativelayout to a textview somewhere. Check your onCreate and see all relativelayout and textviews you declare there.

Comment: Thats the problem. I'm not casting a relativelayout to a textview somewhere.

Comment: Can you find it? If you can see the ...36 more it should tell you more or less what line gives the error. Or post more code and a more complete logcat and it will be easier for us to find it.

Comment: I found the solution, it was very easy but i found it. I did not use the CustomListViewAdapter i made. But thanks for trying to help me!